# Swift - Grouping elements according to their equal features

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift 4, I have:

```
let customers = [Customer(name: "John", country: "US", profession: "Engineer"), Customer(name: "Mary", country: "UK", profession: "Nurse"), Customer(name: "Diana", country: "US", profession: "Engineer"), Customer(name: "Paul", country: "US", profession: "Plumber"), Customer(name: "Sam", country: "UK", profession: "Nurse")]
```

I would like to have for example a function that could filter the elements in `customers`, so that each time the names and professions of at least 2 elements in it are equal, they are added to an array automatically created by this function :

```
var customers1 = [Customer(name: "John", country: "US", profession: "Engineer"), Customer(name: "Diana", country: "US", profession: "Engineer")]
var customers2 = [Customer(name: "Mary", country: "UK", profession: "Nurse"), Customer(name: "Sam", country: "UK", profession: "Nurse")]
```

I searched without success, however I picked some solutions that perhaps could be adapted to this case:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func containsSameElements(as other: [Element]) -> Bool {
        return self[1] == other[1] && self[2] == other[2]
    }
}
```

or

```
func ==<Element : Equatable> (lhs: [[Element]], rhs: [[Element]]) -> Bool {
    return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs, by: ==)
}
```

or

`elementsEqual()`/`contains()` with a loop.

or

a combination of `flatMap()`/`reduce()`/`filter()`.

Thank you.

Comment: That data structure seems like a really bad choice.If all of your arrays will have 3 elements with the first one being an index and the other two being Strings, you'd even better be off using an array of tuples. But anyways why store the index inside the array itself? Please explain what is it you are trying to achieve using this data structure and then someone will hopefully be able to suggest a better data structure to use.

Comment: The `[0]` subscript is not an index, you can replace the numbers in it with a string, but it will always be different from `[2]` and `[3]`. I'll edit it. I want to create an array for each group of duplicates (in the said conditions) in `array OfArrays`.

Comment: If you are storing specific, non-homogenous values, using an Array is a bad idea anyways. It makes handling your specific pieces of data way more complicated than it should be.

Comment: The original data is in the form of `arrayOfArrays`. Before handling the data, I would like to filter but if there is a better solution than creating subarrays to filter it in the said conditions (do you mean creating custom classes?), could you please propose one?

Comment: Filtering that data structure is more complicated IMHO then parsing it first to a more flexible and easy to use format and filtering that later.

Comment: Do you mean parsing `arrayOfArrays` into something like: `let customers = [Customer(name: "John", country: "US", profession: "Engineer"), Customer(name: "Mary", country: "US", profession: "Nurse"), [...]]` and then filtering it? OK, but would the solution really differ a lot in this case? (sorry, not enough reputation to chat)

Comment: Yes, something on those lines. And yes, the solution would differ a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to parse `arrayOfArrays` on my side first, then I'll come to edit this question or delete it and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your feedback and clarification, I would do something like this.

```
struct CountryAndProfession: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let country: String
    let profession: String


    var description: String {
        return "CountryAndProfession{country: \(country), profession: \(profession)}"
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(country)__\(profession)".hashValue
    }
    static func ==(left: CountryAndProfession, right: CountryAndProfession) -> Bool {
        return left.country == right.country && left.profession == right.profession
    }
}

// The Customer Type you apparently are dealing with. (May need a custom init depending on your use case
struct Customer: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let countryAndProfession: CountryAndProfession

    var description: String {
        return "Customer{name: \(name), countryAndProfession: \(countryAndProfession)}"
    }

    // returns a dictionary with the passed customer's CountryAndProfession as the key, and the matching
    static func makeDictionaryWithCountryAndProfession(from customers: [Customer]) -> [CountryAndProfession : [Customer]] {
        var customersArrayDictionary: [CountryAndProfession : [Customer]] = [:]

        customers.forEach { (customer) in
            if customersArrayDictionary.keys.contains(customer.countryAndProfession) {
                customersArrayDictionary[customer.countryAndProfession]?.append(customer)
            }
            else {
                customersArrayDictionary[customer.countryAndProfession] = [customer]
            }
        }
        return customersArrayDictionary
    }

    static func getArraysBasedOnCountries(from customerArray: [Customer]) -> [[Customer]] {
        return Array(makeDictionaryWithCountryAndProfession(from: customerArray).values)
    }
}

let arrayOfArrays = [["John", "A", "A" ], ["Mary", "A", "B" ], ["Diana", "A", "A" ], ["Paul", "B", "B" ], ["Sam", "A", "B" ]]

//If you're dealing with non-predictable data, you should probably have some Optionality
let allCustomers = arrayOfArrays.map{ Customer(name: $0[0], countryAndProfession: CountryAndProfession(country: $0[1], profession: $0[2])) }

let splitCustomers = Customer.getArraysBasedOnCountries(from: allCustomers)
//contains [[John, Diana], [Mary, Sam], [Paul]]
```

I'm still not quite sure what you want your final result to look like (something that is always helpful to put in the question), but you should be able to get the result you're looking for using `makeDictionaryWithCountryAndProfession` combined with the specific `CountryAndProfession` you're looking for or using `.filter`

Comment: I would add that if you have a set of known countries and professions they would be a good candidate for an enum. It would make some of this much simpler.

Comment: No, the countries and professions are not known by advance. This solution is what I was looking for: to be able to group elements of an array according to their selected equal features . Thanks again PEEJWEEJ!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would recommend doing what you're trying to do:

```
struct Customer {
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let profession: String

    func countryMatches(with otherCustomer: Customer) -> Bool {
        return country == otherCustomer.country
    }

    func professionMatches(with otherCustomer: Customer) -> Bool {
        return profession == otherCustomer.profession
    }

    func countryAndProfessionMatch(with otherCustomer: Customer) -> Bool {
        return countryMatches(with: otherCustomer) && professionMatches(with: otherCustomer)
    }

    static func getAllCustomersWithProfessionsAndCountriesMatching(with customer: Customer, from allCustomers: [Customer]) -> [Customer] {
        return allCustomers.filter { customer.countryAndProfessionMatch(with: $0) }
    }
}

let arrayOfArrays = [["John", "A", "A" ], ["Mary", "A", "B" ], ["Diana", "A", "A" ], ["Paul", "B", "B" ], ["Sam", "A", "B" ]]

//If you're dealing with non-predictable data, you should probably have some Optionality
let allCustomers = arrayOfArrays.map{ Customer(name: $0[0], country: $0[1], profession: $0[2]) }

let allCustomersMatchingJohnProperties = Customer.getAllCustomersWithProfessionsAndCountriesMatching(with: allCustomers[0], from: allCustomers)  
// contains John and Diane

let allCustomersMatchingMaryProperties = Customer.getAllCustomersWithProfessionsAndCountriesMatching(with: allCustomers[1], from: allCustomers)  
// contains Mary and Sam
```

I believe this does what you're looking to do, but with a more structured/maintainable approach.

`getAllCustomersWithProfessionsAndCountriesMatching` is almost definitely way too long, but left it that way to be clear for the answer. I would advice renaming it to fit your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What I need exactly is to identify in `allCustomers` those having the same country and the same profession, and automatically create a property with them, but not based on another customer. For example, I would have property1 with all customers from the US and engineers, and property2 with all customers from the UK and nurses. It's creating a property if at least 2 customers in `allCustomers` have the same country and profession that is important. I'm sorry if I'm not clear. I edited the first post.

Comment: @TommyV. Posted a new answer based on your clarification. It's different enough that I didn't want to edit this one.